# checking field update on multiple child records

Tags: apex, trigger, controller, validation, custom-field

I have a requirement to check Terminated__c flag on multiple child records (lead_Custom__c) and if it is true, then update the Terminated__c flag on Parent record (contact).

Below is the apex class:

```
public with sharing class Lead_TerminationCheck {
    public void UpdateFields(List<Lead_Custom__c> newList) {
        List<Contact> updateList = new List<Contact>();
        Map<id,List<Lead_Custom__c>> mapParentIDAndChild = new Map<id,List<Lead_Custom__c>>();
        boolean flag;
        set<Id> parenetTrue = new set<Id>();
        for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : newList) {
            parenetTrue.add(objChild.Contact__c);
        }
        for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : [select id , Terminated__c , Contact__c from Lead_Custom__c where Contact__c IN: parenetTrue] ){
            if(mapParentIDAndChild.containsKey(objChild.Contact__c)) {
                mapParentIDAndChild.get(objChild.Contact__c).add(objChild);
            } else {
                mapParentIDAndChild.put(objChild.Contact__c,new List<Lead_Custom__c>{objChild});
            }
        }
        for(Id objId : mapParentIDAndChild.keySet()) {
            flag = true;
            for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : mapParentIDAndChild.get(objId)) {
                if(objChild.Terminated__c == false){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true) {
                updateList.add(new Contact(Id = objId , Terminated__c = true));
            } 
        }
        if(!updateList.isEmpty()) {
            update updateList;
        }

    }
}
```

The above apex class is working only if all the child records have Termination__c as true. But, is there any way to check the parent has more than one child record and if yes, then even if any one the child record has this flag set to true, then parent's terminated flag should be updated.

Can anyone please suggest the changes to the above apex class so that I can get this done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather do a query on the parent.

First collect the ids of the contacts from new list.

```
set<Id> parenetTrue = new set<Id>();
for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : newList) {
    parenetTrue.add(objChild.Contact__c);
}
```

Then

```
Contact__c[] contacts = [SELECT (SELECT ID,Terminated__c FROM leadCustom_1__r) FROM Contact WHERE Id IN : parenetTrue];
for(Contact contactObj: contacts){
    if(contactObj.leadCustom_1__r.size() > 1){
        for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : contactObj.leadCustom_1__r){
            if(objChild.Terminated__c == true){
                updateList.add(new Contact(Id = contactObj.Id, Terminated__c = true));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error that Lead_Custom__r does not exists. The lookup relationship name is leadCustom_1__c. Even when I try, leadCustom_1__r, that didnt work. How to call the child field here?

Comment: Use whatever child relationship name you have. I had preassunrd that.. also as i am checking the condition in directly in the query so you don't need to check explicitly

Comment: using this given query, even if the contact has one child record with terminated checked, the contact's terminated is getting checked. If I increase the count to 2 and check the size for >1, the contact's terminated is getting checked only if any 2 of child records are marked true for terminated checkbox. As per my requirement, i need to check if the parent has more than one child and if any of the child is marked true, then parent should be true. Please suggest

Comment: @SK_112 try the updated code

Comment: Thanks @rahul. It is working as expected. As a final suggestion, could you please suggest if there any way i can uncheck the parent terminated checkbox if none of the child's checkbox is true?

Comment: @SK_112 count all the false values and check that against the number of child records for each contact If the count equals to number of records then update that to false.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is backwards.

```
        flag = true;
        for(Lead_Custom__c objChild : mapParentIDAndChild.get(objId)) {
            if(objChild.Terminated__c == false){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == true) {
            updateList.add(new Contact(Id = objId , Terminated__c = true));
        }
```

You are setting `flag` to `false` if *any* `Lead_Custom__c` record has the `Terminated__c` field set to `false`. That is the opposite of what you stated you want, for `Terminated__c` to be `true` if any `Lead_Custom__c` record has it set to `true`.

You need to swap the initial value of `flag` to `false`, look for `objChild.Terminated__c` to be `true`, set `flag` to be `true`. You may also wish to store your Contacts and check whether its Terminated flag *needs* to change, to be efficient in your updates.